# Making the statusbar have a color, yet be transparent

Tags: android, xml, material-design, statusbar

## This is my current layout in action:

[image: screenshot]

## The xml file producing this looks like:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/toolbarTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

## The style that the theme uses:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

The expected result was that the status bar would be colored in the primary_dark color, yet the drawer should be on top of it (like in Google apps), yet I get this result. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your activity has `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and maybe `android:clipToPadding="true"`but bare in mind this is for later version of android only

Comment: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` is already set on the LinearLayout, if I set it anywhere else the toolbar (actually the entire app) appears to be below the statusbar

Comment: @tofiffe try removing this `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` or making it false

Comment: if I do that the drawer is no longer drawn below the icons on the statusbar

Comment: @tofiffe is that not according to design guidelines?? http://www.google.co.in/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: my intention was to get as close as possible to Google apps, where the drawer is drawn below the statusbar and statusbar still has the defined color

Comment: @tofiffe which google app are you referring. Gmail ,inbox, Play music ( which had drawer below the status bar before) all of them have the drawer just as in the guidelines link posted in my previous comment. I think its better you follow the new design guidelines.

Comment: for me Gmail and Google Play are styled this way and it seems really apealing to me, therefore I'd like to reproduce it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85259/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-tofiffe).